# Can a pwa work in background even if browser is closed?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I want to develop a simply phone pwa application for mobile.

Can other party receive a signal / notification /event/ whatever that indicates that someone tries to reach him ? (Even when browser is closed) ?

Comment: No. Javascript needs a Javascript engine to run. No engine running === no code running.